# How to set Background image in GLKViewController iPhone OpenGLES?

Tags: ios, image, opengl-es, background

I'm drawing a line using OpenGL on the iPhone. I used `GLView` and `GLKView` delegates to draw the line. But now I want to set a background image to `GLKViewController`, and on the background image, I want to draw the line. I have tried to set a background image using `UIImageView`, but the image is appearing above on the (`GLKView`) drawn line.

How can I set a background image to the `GLKViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way should be to add additional view with background image (such as you proposed - but you need to set it behind OpenGL view). Try this:

```
[RootViewController.view addSubview: BackgroundView belowSubview: OpenGLView];
OpenGLView.opaque = NO;
```

But this will bring some FPS penalty (Apple recommends to use opaque OpenGL view for performance reason). More correct approach is to draw background via OpenGL as fullscreen quad.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to state that the accepted answer is a very bad one... You will lose an almost immediate 20fps even on the newer devices (iPhone 5, iPad 2 & newer) by turning off opaque. The performance penalty is horrible and should not be taken lightly.

You can set a background in OpenGL and keep your opaque. Convert the UIImage to an OpenGL texture and render it. Depending on your OpenGL environment, this can be done a number of ways easily.